# Javascript for 3 dynamic drop down

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a make model year car database and I have the following form that selects model based on make.

```
    <? 

 $hostname = "";
 $database = "";
 $username = "";
 $password = "";

 $mysql_link = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("can't connect to mysql");
 $mysql_select = mysql_select_db($database,$mysql_link) or die ("can't select db");
  ?> 

 <html> 
 <head> 
 <title>Dynamic Dropdown</title> 
 <script language="javascript"> 
 function setOptions(chosen) { 
   var selbox = document.myform.selectmodel; 

   selbox.options.length = 0; 
   if (chosen == "0") { 
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('First select a car','0');

   } 
   <? 
   $car_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM make") or die(mysql_error()); 
   while(@($c=mysql_fetch_array($car_result))) 
   { 
   ?> 
     if (chosen == "<?=$c['make'];?>") { 

     <? 
     $c_id = $c['make']; 
     $mod_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM model WHERE make='$c_id'") or die(mysql_error());
      while(@($m=mysql_fetch_array($mod_result))) 
     { 
     ?> 
       selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new 
       Option('<?=$m['model'];?>','<?=$m['model'];?>'); 
     <? 
     } 
     ?> 
     } 
   <? 
   } 
   ?>  
   } 
  </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
 <form name="myform"><div align="center"> 
 <p>
     <select name="selectcar" size="1" 
     onchange="setOptions(document.myform.selectcar.options 
      [document.myform.selectcar.selectedIndex].value);"> 
       <option value="0" selected>Select a car</option> 
      <? 
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM make") or die(mysql_error()); 
     while(@($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))) 
      { 
      ?> 
       <option value="<?=$r['make'];?>">
          <?=$r['make'];?>
       </option> 
       <? 
      } 
    ?> 
     </select>
       <br>
        <br> 
   <select name="selectmodel" size="1"> 
     <option value=" " selected>First select a car</option> 
    </select>
     <br>
     <br>
      <select name="optthree" size="1">
       <option value=" " selected="selected">Please select one of the options  above               first</option>
      </select>
         </p>
       <p>
           <input type="button" name="go" value="Value Selected" 
        onclick="alert(document.myform.selectmodel.options 
     [document.myform.selectmodel.selectedIndex].value);"> 
         </p>
    </div></form> 
      </body> 
    </html>
```

I need to add the javascript code and form code to make the 3rd drop down box show the year based on the make and model.

Thanks for your assistance.

Here is the updated javascript to populate and select the year drop down

```
 <script language="javascript"> 
  function setOptions(chosen) { 
  var selbox = document.myform.selectmodel; 

      selbox.options.length = 0; 
    if (chosen == "0") { 
         selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('First select a car','0');

      } 
     <? 
       $car_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM make") or die(mysql_error()); 
     while(@($c=mysql_fetch_array($car_result))) 
      { 
     ?> 
         if (chosen == "<?=$c['make'];?>") { 

           <? 
         $c_id = $c['make']; 
              $mod_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM model WHERE make='$c_id'") or die                   (mysql_error());
   while(@($m=mysql_fetch_array($mod_result))) 
     { 
  ?> 
         selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new 
       Option('<?=$m['model'];?>','<?=$m['model'];?>'); 
     <? 
     } 
      ?> 
     if (chosen == "<?=$m['make'];?>") { 

    <? 
     $m_id = $c['make']; 
       $mod_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM year WHERE make='$c_id' AND model='$m_id'") or    die(mysql_error());
          while(@($y=mysql_fetch_array($year_result))) 
      { 
        ?> 
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new 
      Option('<?=$y['year'];?>','<?=$y['year'];?>'); 
      <? 
           } 
     <? 
    } 
   ?> 
    } 
   </script>
```

Comment: Great, that's the problem succinctly defined. What problem are you having, exactly?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the creaky, antiquated `mysql_query` method? It's deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. [You should be using PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for this kind of database access.

Comment: Agree with tadman PDO or mysqli are the current recommendations based on the docs.  The other thing I think you should reconsider outside of your immediate issue is how you are mixing php with your HTML.  While there's nothing that says this is absolutely wrong, IMHO it's a mess to work with.  This would be much simpler if you divide the PHP from the presentation (AngularJS is very helpful for this sort of thing, but there's lots of other options).

Comment: I have a make, model, and year table. The year table is id, make, model and year. I need add the form code and and javascript to select the years the model was made based on the make and model

Comment: @Kenny, heh, yes I understand the problem. I was trying to point out that this site exists to assist people, not to do free coding for them. Can I suggest you give it a bash, and to report back if you run into a _specific_ problem? Read the FAQ when you get a mo too, it's actually quite good.

Comment: (Are you looking to kick off an AJAX operation when a menu changes, to read the options for the later menus, or will you hold everything in JavaScript variables on the page?)

Comment: I understand I will give it a stab and report back

Comment: I have added the updated javascript code to select the year dropdown

Comment: I just need the year to populate in the 3rd drop down. I need to make sure that the javascript modifications are correct

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been abandoned with no resolution, and the user appears to have requested account deletion.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, your code is correct if it works `:)`. However this code is getting a bit complex, so perhaps I might offer some ways to improve it.

Firstly, you are mixing HTML and PHP in a way that makes it hard to follow what's going on - it would be much easier to deal with if you switch to a template engine. A good way towards that is to move all your PHP to the start of your PHP file, and then it is easy to move to a separate file. Consider this code:

```
 <select name="selectcar" size="1" 
 onchange="setOptions(document.myform.selectcar.options 
  [document.myform.selectcar.selectedIndex].value);"> 
   <option value="0" selected>Select a car</option> 
  <? 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM make") or die(mysql_error()); 
 while(@($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))) 
  { 
  ?> 
   <option value="<?=$r['make'];?>">
      <?=$r['make'];?>
   </option> 
   <? 
  } 
?> 
 </select>
```

Here's how I would do that:

```
<?php /* Start of document * ?>
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM make") or die(mysql_error()); 

// Other PHP...
?>

<!-- HTML here -->

<select
    name="selectcar"
    size="1" 
    onchange="setOptions(document.myform.selectcar.options[document.myform.selectcar.selectedIndex].value);"
>
    <option value="0" selected>Select a car</option> 
    <?php while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $r['make'] ?>">
            <?php echo $r['make'] ?>
        </option>
    <?php endwhile ?>
```

You can see here that in the HTML markup, all PHP statements are only single line, and I eschew the brace form of statements for the colon form, since the end statements (`endfor`, `endwhile`, `endforeach` etc are much easier to read). Also, single statements do not need a semi-colon line ending, which makes for slightly clearer markup.

I've also only used the long form of the PHP opening statement (`<?php`) since the short form can be turned off in your server configuration, and thus is not very portable between servers.

I don't recommend you use the `@` error suppression mechanism, since it might cause you to miss a bug prior to going live. It is much better to test your code thoroughly on your local machine, and to turn off on-screen error reporting on your live server. Also, switch to a better database library if you can - the `mysql` library is deprecated, and will be removed from a future version of PHP.

The inline event attributes are not part of HTML5 (`onchange` etc) although they will work in browsers for legacy reasons. It is therefore better to use unobtrusive event attaching, such as this in jQuery:

```
$('select[name=selectcar]').change(function() { .. });
```

Your JavaScript declaration currently won't pass W3C validation. Rather than this:

```
<script language="javascript">
```

you need this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Next, your JavaScript is dynamically generated, which will make it a real pain to debug. It is better to write this as plain text, containing no PHP at all, and then use an array from PHP as input data. (There are use-cases for PHP inside JavaScript, but I suggest you avoid it for now).

I'd say the purpose of the `setOptions()` JavaScript function isn't clear. It looks like you are listing the contents of your database, and then doing a whole set of comparisons without using a client-side loop. Here I would recommend you take a snapshot of your project as it stands (ideally with a VCS such as Git, but failing that a folder copy is okay) and then rewrite this bit.

I can't advise too much here as it is not clear what you are trying to do. Bear in mind that, as it stands, the menu data in the JavaScript comparisons is only correct when the page is served. If each drop-down is dependent on the value of the previous one, then you may need an AJAX server lookup, as I said in the comments. If not, then render your data as an array (PHP's `json_encode` is useful here) and then access it in JavaScript using a loop construct.

Comment: I have the site working now by passing $_post variables to a new page for each new select box. Just used this code sample because I wanted to use dynamic updating to make it more efficient.

Comment: Please do read my extensive answer notwithstanding, I would hate to have wasted my time on it! There is plenty to fix - best of luck with it.